# How can attribute of one node of a link be copied from the other node of the same link?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create a link between a turtle of one breed and another turtle of another breed, and then to copy the value of an attribute of the turtle at one node of the link into an attribute of the other turtle at the other node of the same link.

I tried:

```
to go
  ask one-of apples [
    create-link-to one-of oranges
    ask-mood]
end

to ask-mood
  set others-mood [my-mood] of other-end
end
```

And (obviously) got the error message "Only a link can get the OTHER-END from a turtle."

Please could you advice the code that I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give an answer without a working example. You have a bit of a conceptual problem - if two edges link to the same turtle, which turtle is supposed to provide the value for the others-mood? In the following code I have ignored that and just randomly selected the one to provide the value.

You need to change contexts by selecting a link and then the other end of the link is available. See the following for a full model that you can adapt to your code.

```
turtles-own [mood others-mood]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set mood random-float 1
  ]
  ask turtles
  [ create-link-to one-of other turtles
    set others-mood [mood] of [other-end] of one-of my-links
  ]
end
```